# how do i Save a photo from the internet?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

hi i created 1 apps on that app i am getting photos from flickr using json and viewing these photos as thumbnail and also slideshow , if suppose the user want to save some photos those from flickr how to do i was just doing these through NSDefaultManager bt dosen't work,

```
    - (IBAction)saveImage
    {
        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,     NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
        NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDirectory      stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"savedImage.png"];
        [imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:NO];   
    }
```

Comment: Your code looks fine. What about it doesn't work?

Comment: "doesn't work" is not a failure description.

Answer (score 0):

```
     try this code for the same//.


NSString *videoDocPath1 = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[[[[NSBundle mainBundle]  resourcePath] stringByDeletingLastPathComponent] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Documents"]];
NSString *videofilePath1;
videofilePath1 = [videoDocPath1 stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"screensever.mp4"]]; 
[ScreenseverVideo writeToFile:videofilePath1 atomically:YES];
```